# Get a list of years from solr

Tags: solr

I want to get a list of years like:

```
2015(2)
2014(4)
2013(8)
```

I set my params based on this wiki:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#rangefaceting

But as soon as I add the last four params my search returns nothing.

My params:

```
facet=true
&facet.field=abc_category
&facet.field=abc_publicDate
&facet.mincount=1
&fq=documentKind:(%22Cve%22)
&hl=true
&hl.fl=abstract
&hl.simple.post=%253C%252Fmark%253E
&hl.simple.pre=%253Cmark%253E
&q=*:*
&rows=12
&start=0
&facet.range=abc_publicDate
&f.abc_publicDate.facet.range.gap=+1YEAR
&f.abc_publicDate.facet.range.start=NOW/YEAR-5YEARS
&f.abc_publicDate.facet.range.end=NOW
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

change

`&f.abc_publicDate.facet.range.gap=+1YEAR`

to

`&f.abc_publicDate.facet.range.gap=%2B1YEAR`

So, url encode the `+` sign to `%2B`